# how to persist products in a web selling site?

Tags: java, web-applications, persistence

I have a web selling site and intend to add new products now and then. Should I have a databas that the application reads the products from or should i hard code them? A product is some description text, an image-link and a title.

I mean, it must be harder to redeploy the application every time i add a new product. But it may be more efficient then looking in the database all the time. Setting the database cache may be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the product information in a database and read the data into a ConcurrentHashMap (or whatever works for you) and have the benefits of both. The map can be reloaded on a schedule or on demand through a web action you would create.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer to a good question. Why would anyone click down my question? Contact me and we see who knows more!